# An input loop for reading a file

Tags: c++, file, loops, input

I'm a beginner in programming and I need help with this snippet of code presented in my book.

```
for (My_type var; ist >> var;) { // read until end of file 
// maybe check that var is valid 
// do something with var

}

if (ist.fail()) {
ist.clear(); 
char ch; 
// the error function is created into the book : 
if (!(ist >> ch && ch == '|')) error("Bad termination of input\n"); 

}
// carry on : we found end of file or terminator
```

This example is about reading values from  a file. I've tried to use this but I'm having some troubles in understanding how it works :

1. If I try to test the stream state after the loop I get both `eof` and `fail` state, how is that possibile ? How to avoid triggering both `fail` and `eof` ?
2. When is EOF triggered exactly ? From my test it seems to be triggered when I reach the last value of a sequence, is this definition correct ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> If I try to test the stream state after the loop I get both eof and fail state, how is that possibile ? How to avoid triggering both fail and eof ?

It is possible if there is a character that cannot be converted to `My_type`, and that character is the last character in the file. Then, `failbit` and `eofbit` will be set.

> When is EOF triggered exactly ? From my test it seems to be triggered when I reach the last value of a sequence, is this definition correct ?

Yes, `eofbit` gets set when the last character is read.

Quoting from [`std::basic_istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> The extraction stops if one of the following conditions are met:
>
> - end-of-file occurs on the input sequence;
> - inserting in the output sequence fails (in which case the character to be inserted is not extracted);
> - an exception occurs (in which case the exception is caught, and only rethrown if failbit is enabled in exceptions()).

Comment: I think I'm understanding this loop better now, but I still have a problem that needs to be clarified, if both `eof` and  `fail` get triggered after the loop, then the test for `fail` will be true everytime. Now suppose I want to read 10 integers from a file and accept only `eof` as terminator, I will read using the for loop and at the end I will have both `eof` and  `fail` up. At this point what can I do ? I can't throw an exception using error if the read fails because it will happen for sure as I understand. I'm not really understanding the book example.

Comment: @Piero What you could do is first check for `eof`, then check `fail`. This way, you notice when the file ended, but don't care if the last character was valid or not.

Comment: So I think I  should probably assume that the author of the book wrote a wrong example.